# combine foreach and for loop using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have some code which loops through my data table and i used the `item` variable well. But my problem is `i` needs to iterate through, it needs to be + 1 from the last number it was on. It needs to come out of its loops once the `foreach` has finished.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateExcelDoc excell_app = new CreateExcelDoc();
    //creates the main header

    COLUMNSTableAdapter adapterTableName = new COLUMNSTableAdapter();

    DataTable table = adapterTableName.GetData(tableName); // Get the data table.
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
    {
        foreach (var item in row.ItemArray) // Loop over the items.
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++)
            {
                excell_app.createHeaders(1, 1, "" + item + "", i, i, 1, "black", false, 10, "n");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My code will loop 30 times before it gets to the next row in the data table. This is wrong and I am trying to define the count to be a count of the items in the data table

Comment: You need to calculate amount of cells?

Comment: Can you please clarify this question? You have 3 answers, and nobody seems to be able to figure out what the heck you want this code to do. Think Big Picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your comment you can use another variable:
As @Grundy has suggested in comment - if you use an Array you can use Length of it:

```
int j = 1;
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++, j++)
    {
       excell_app.createHeaders(1, 1, "" + row.ItemArray[i] + "", j, j, 1, "black", false, 10, "n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `ItemArray` is array so it does not have `Count` property, use `Length` instead

Comment: All `i` needs to do is increment each time there is a new `item`. Once there are no more items then `i` must stop incrementing.

Comment: @Grundy Thanks and right, I hope OP's ItemArray is an array :)

Comment: error: `Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: @PriceCheaperton It seems that I had more luck in guessing what you were trying to do. Please try to better describe your problems - it will spare your time and others efforts.

Answer (score 3):

> My code will loop 30 times before it gets to the next row in the data table. This is wrong and I am trying to define the count to be a count of the items in the data table

Then Why don't you use one for loop like this ?

```
for(int i = 1; i< row.ItemArray.Length+1; i++)
{
   var item = row.ItemArray[i];
   excell_app.createHeaders(1, 1, "" + item + "", i, i, 1, "black", false, 10, "n");
}
```

Comment: Well no because `i` doesnt actually even loop

Comment: All `i` needs to do is increment each time there is a new `item`. Once there are no more items then `i` must stop incrementing.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton so you want `i` to be the total item count in the final?

Comment: `i` is just an incrementing value which references the Excel column ranges. eg, `[1,1]` and in my code its, `i,i`. So everytime i get a new `item` i should have a new incremented `i`. So if the total items in my datatable is 3. I expect the last incremented `i` to be `3`

Comment: @PriceCheaperton hmm,so i should be the column count of the current row?

Comment: in debug `i` seems to be always `1`... This is incorrect my friend.

Comment: I have to set `i = 1` because 0,0 is not a valid Excel location. But even so your code does not increment

Comment: @PriceCheaperton I understand that but I don't understand why don't you accept my first answer? I start it from 1 now and it should increment as long as there is an item

Comment: `row.ItemArray.Length;` will never work as it will always return 1 and by the time it gets to the inner loop, the value for `i` is reset.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton if it is always return 1 what is the point of second foreach loop? if you are worried about the loop never execute than you can use row.ItemArray.Length+1 as condition

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

> All `i` needs to do is increment each time there is a new item. Once there are no more items then i must stop incrementing.
>
> in that case i need to write something which stops it going back to zero for a new row..

```
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
{
    foreach (var item in row.ItemArrai) // Loop over the items.
    {
        i++;
        for (int j = 1; j < 30; j++)
        {
            excell_app.createHeaders(1, 1, "" + item + "", j, j, 1, "black", false, 10, "n");
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: that doesn't change anything

Comment: This will loop 30 times before it gets to the next row in the data table. I am trying to define the count to be a count of the items in the data table.

Comment: All `i` needs to do is increment each time there is a new `item`. Once there are no more items then `i` must stop incrementing.

Comment: It should not increment 30 times!

Comment: @PriceCheaperton It Won't! it will only count how many items there were. how many iterations the second `foreach` ran through.

Comment: I have just tried it and `i` loops 30 times before the next `item`

Comment: @PriceCheaperton You need to be clear about what you are trying to achieve. In my current code i indeed is incremented 30 times because it's part of a `for` loop. that's what it does. `j` on the other hand.. count exactly how many iterations were there in the second foreach. meaning how many items there are.

Comment: I am being clear, I loop through my datatable of items but at the same time, for each `item` i loop through i need to increment `i` so if i am on count of 4, i.e 4th item from my data table then i expect `i` to be 4. At the moment nobody has management to get `i` to increment correctly.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton here, i flipped the names. `i` will be 4 on the 4th item.

Comment: Well no the inner loop is firing 30 times after each `item`. Sorry friend this is wrong

Comment: `i` is also always `0` in your code.. Looping through the items, its clear that `i` will always reset to `0`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46107/discussion-between-i3arnon-and-pricecheaperton)